# Can't get the reason for a deadlock

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection, clr, windbg

I have a mixed application (boost, ACE, cli, C#).

I've loaded dump into WinDbg and here are my investigations:

1) There are 25 threads:

```
0:024> ~
#  0  Id: 22d8.2e1c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eb6f000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: 22d8.2d90 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eb6c000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: 22d8.2ab0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eb65000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: 22d8.17c4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ea36000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: 22d8.1254 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ea33000 Unfrozen
   5  Id: 22d8.227c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9cf000 Unfrozen
   6  Id: 22d8.f94 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9cc000 Unfrozen
   7  Id: 22d8.23e8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9c0000 Unfrozen
   8  Id: 22d8.19d8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9c6000 Unfrozen
   9  Id: 22d8.19fc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9bd000 Unfrozen
  10  Id: 22d8.1ec8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9ba000 Unfrozen
  11  Id: 22d8.149c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9b7000 Unfrozen
  12  Id: 22d8.1dec Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9b4000 Unfrozen
  13  Id: 22d8.2e50 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9b1000 Unfrozen
  14  Id: 22d8.19d0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9ae000 Unfrozen
  15  Id: 22d8.2f80 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9ab000 Unfrozen
  16  Id: 22d8.1218 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9a8000 Unfrozen
  17  Id: 22d8.2874 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9a5000 Unfrozen
  18  Id: 22d8.1f7c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9a2000 Unfrozen
  19  Id: 22d8.292c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e99f000 Unfrozen
  20  Id: 22d8.2c6c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e99c000 Unfrozen
  21  Id: 22d8.27ec Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9c9000 Unfrozen
  22  Id: 22d8.ab0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ea39000 Unfrozen
  23  Id: 22d8.1d54 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ea3f000 Unfrozen
  24  Id: 22d8.2ee8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ea3c000 Unfrozen
```

22 of them are managed threads

```
0:024> !threads
ThreadCount:      22
UnstartedThread:  1
BackgroundThread: 20
PendingThread:    1
DeadThread:       0
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 2e1c 015a8d58     26020 Cooperative 00000000:00000000 015a2f18 1     STA (GC) 
   2    2 2ab0 015b6b90     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
   3    3 17c4 016501e0   102a220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
   5    4 227c 0425f080   1020220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
   7    7 23e8 07628058     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
   8    8 19d8 07659a08     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
   9    9 19fc 07667418     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  10   10 1ec8 07668d18     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  11   11 149c 0766abc8     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  12   12 1dec 076724e0     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  13   13 2e50 07672a28     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  14   14 19d0 0767a448     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  15   15 2f80 0767a990     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  16   16 1218 0767ba88     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  17   17 2874 076811c0     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  18   18 1f7c 076826e0     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  19   19 292c 07683c00     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  20   20 2c6c 07682198     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn 
  21   31 27ec 098dfac8   8039220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  22    5  ab0 098e0fe8   8029220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  23   35 1d54 098e0558   1039220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  24   38 2ee8 098df038      1600 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 015a2f18 0     Ukn
```

3) I've got callstack for these threads (with `~*kvn`) and searched for NtWaitForSingleObject:

```
00 00fae970 74f02cc7 000001c8 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 049ff670 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 07adf63c 7769de07 00000980 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0817d4f0 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0858ed00 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0868ed48 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 087cebf0 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0890ed00 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 08a4ecd0 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 08c4f600 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 08d8f9a8 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 08ecfab8 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0900f9c8 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0914f928 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0928f890 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 093cf480 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0950f630 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 0474ebf0 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 07d9ed38 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
00 096cf77c 7769de07 00000980 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
```

There are 3 events, that are blocking threads:

1. As far as i understood, the GC thread (which is in cooperative mode) waits untill all other managed threads will stop their work and will give sign, that GC can start its work.
2. Threads that are waiting for a handle `000001bc` are already waiting for a GC.

All of them have identical top of call stack:

```
00 049ff670 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
01 049ff6e4 7220a0ab 000001bc ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99 (FPO: [SEH])
02 049ff714 7220a0f2 00000000 e1a41a23 00000000 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x33 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 049ff764 7220a077 00000000 e1a41adb 0159d398 clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 049ff79c 7221499e ffffffff 00000000 00000000 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
05 049ff7b0 72211c25 00000000 e1a41a87 016501e0 clr!WKS::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x34 (FPO: [1,0,0])
06 049ff800 722c53c0 098deaf0 722c9fe6 e1a41527 clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+0x231 (FPO: [0,13,0])
07 049ff808 722c9fe6 e1a41527 00000001 00000000 clr!GCCoopHackNoThread::GCCoopHackNoThread+0x2e (FPO: [0,0,4])
```

3. There is a third handle - `00000980` which is blocking threads 6 and 24.

Here are call stacks of these two threads:

```
   6  Id: 22d8.f94 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7e9cc000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 07adf63c 7769de07 00000980 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
01 07adf6b0 7769dc8b 0429da58 0429da58 00000002 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xd0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
02 07adf6dc 7769dcb5 07adf71c 67691348 67737850 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0xa0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 07adf6e4 67691348 67737850 f76f5d88 0429da58 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 07adf71c 6768e470 07adf73c 07adf740 07adf74c ucrtbase!__crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator()<<lambda_5b71d36f03204c0beab531769a5b5694>,<lambda_be2b3da3f62db62e9dad5dc70221a656> &,<lambda_8f9ce462984622f9bf76b59e2aaaf805> >+0x48 (FPO: [SEH])
05 07adf754 776ecc7a 0429da58 015b85c8 00000102 ucrtbase!destroy_fls+0xe0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
06 07adf77c 776a2dde 015b85c8 e7200ce7 00000000 ntdll!RtlProcessFlsData+0xf8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
07 07adf818 776a29dc ffffffff 00000102 74b10000 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x32 (FPO: [SEH])
08 07adf8ec 74f17194 00000000 00000102 74b10000 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x4c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
09 07adf900 74b1c1c8 74b10000 00000000 74b1c0d0 KERNELBASE!FreeLibraryAndExitThread+0x34 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0a 07adf93c 76f57c04 01602f40 76f57be0 e7636a34 mswsock!SockAsyncThread+0x11e (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0b 07adf950 776dad2f 01602f40 e7200d67 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0c 07adf998 776dacfa ffffffff 776c00b0 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f (FPO: [SEH])
0d 07adf9a8 00000000 74b1c0d0 01602f40 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  24  Id: 22d8.2ee8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ea3c000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 096cf77c 7769de07 00000980 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
01 096cf7f0 7769dc8b 67737340 075af238 00000002 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xd0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
02 096cf81c 7769dcb5 096cf85c 67691598 67737850 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0xa0 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 096cf824 67691598 67737850 f9ae52c8 67737340 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 096cf85c 6768ed7b 096cf890 096cf87c 096cf884 ucrtbase!__crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator()<<lambda_3518db117f0e7cdb002338c5d3c47b6c>,<lambda_b2ea41f6bbb362cd97d94c6828d90b61> &,<lambda_abdedf541bb04549bc734292b4a045d4> >+0x48 (FPO: [SEH])
05 096cf8ac 6768e4f6 00000000 096cf8d8 776c96de ucrtbase!DllMainDispatch+0x17b (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
06 096cf8b8 776c96de 67660000 00000002 00000000 ucrtbase!__acrt_DllMain+0x16 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
07 096cf8d8 776c9658 6768e4e0 67660000 00000002 ntdll!LdrxCallInitRoutine+0x16
08 096cf928 776e5b33 00000002 00000000 e9e10d3b ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x43 (FPO: [SEH])
09 096cf9c4 776daa54 e9e10eeb 00000000 00000000 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x106 (FPO: [SEH])
0a 096cfa14 776da9d0 00000000 00000000 096cfa30 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x6e (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0b 096cfa1c 00000000 096cfa30 77680000 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

The top ich identical. And both are waiting for the same event:

```
0:024> dt ntdll!_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION 67737850
   +0x000 DebugInfo        : 0x07589a98 _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
   +0x004 LockCount        : 0n-10
   +0x008 RecursionCount   : 0n1
   +0x00c OwningThread     : 0x000023e8 Void
   +0x010 LockSemaphore    : 0x00000980 Void
   +0x014 SpinCount        : 0xfa0
```

And here I can see, that the owner of this event is thread Nr. 7 (23e8).

And here I've stucked:

1. thread 0 had triggered GC, and starts waiting for all managed threads
2. thread 7 had started waiting until GC is finished.
3. thread 6 seems to be an unmanaged thread, so we can ignore it
4. thread 24 waits until thread 7 will release handle `0x980`
5. thread 0 will not continue until thread 24 will start to wait for GC (`WaitUntilGCComplete`)
6. thread 7 will not release handle `0x980` until thread 0 is ready.

Deadlock.

I don't see any line in callstack of the thread 7 where this handle could be set. And i have no idea, how could i found out the reason of the deadlock.

Do you have any advice?

Update, as requested in comment:

Here is the output of `!analyze -v -hang`

```
0:007> !analyze -v -hang
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.cxr;r)
eax=00000001 ebx=07628058 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=000001bc
eip=776bc33c esp=0817d4f4 ebp=0817d564 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc:
776bc33c c20c00          ret     0Ch

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  000023e8

PROCESS_NAME:  DataAcquisition.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  cfffffff

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_HANG

WATSON_BKT_EVENT:  AppHang

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  unknown

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  0.0.0.0

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  0

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  bbbbbbb4

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5a7c8dca

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  2.0.10.6

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:   DataAcquisition

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.3.9600.17415 (winblue_r4.141028-1500)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  5885d70d8e46f0eabba57b93b12e832f6e89fef5

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  fee227812939995a1d0ec519e5d34e45f0278989

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

PRODUCT_TYPE:  3

SUITE_MASK:  272

DUMP_FLAGS:  8000c07

DUMP_TYPE:  3

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  D116761

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-01-2018 18:23:18.0286

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.400 x86fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  clr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: 2e1c

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   7   22d8.23e8 Pseudo Thread Handle   

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~7s;k;;

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
BLOCKING_THREAD:  000023e8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BusyHang

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  9ced3fd11653de6459589f9d85e80a71659b8f04

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  35554e4c1cf9537ccfa6541f1738ec2b92873870

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 74f02cc7 to 776bc33c

STACK_TEXT:  
0817d4f0 74f02cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
0817d564 7220a0ab 000001bc ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99
0817d594 7220a0f2 00000000 ed2c38a3 00000000 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x33
0817d5e4 7220a077 00000000 ed2c3b5b 0159d398 clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a
0817d61c 7221499e ffffffff 00000000 00000000 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152
0817d630 72211c25 00000000 ed2c3b07 07628058 clr!WKS::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x34
0817d680 72388444 ed2c3a43 00000000 07628058 clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+0x231
0817d704 0829e382 3259f8be 721ffa00 0817d748 clr!JIT_RareDisableHelper+0x24
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0817d738 0829e1fe 0829e231 3259f8be 721ffa00 0x829e382
0817d7a4 0829de54 00000014 0817da54 0817d830 0x829e1fe
0817d830 09518e12 0817de98 01e9d821 00000030 0x829de54
0817db2c 095180bc 0817de98 04230d90 0817f350 0x9518e12
0817e044 0437bf99 0817ead0 095488f0 07628058 0x95180bc
0817e070 09513481 0758e698 0817f350 0817ead0 0x437bf99
0817ee94 09545fa9 0817f2c0 00000000 0817f5e4 0x9513481
0817f638 081fb947 0817f82c 097b5d38 3259f8be 0x9545fa9
0817f6b8 0437b535 0817f82c 081f68e0 07628058 0x81fb947
0817f6e4 081fa751 04259828 097b5d38 0817f82c 0x437b535
0817f78c 0437b1fc 0817f814 0817f80c 081f6870 0x81fa751
0817f7bc 0802e1c4 04259828 0817f82c 0817f80c 0x437b1fc
0817f888 0437a01d 0802c4f0 07628058 0817fb9c 0x802e1c4
0817f8b0 0802d897 04259828 07628058 04264ec0 0x437a01d
0817fb8c 04379f56 0802c4d8 07628058 0817fc14 0x802d897
0817fbb4 0802cf80 04259828 3259f8be 721ffa00 0x4379f56
0817fbe8 0802cf1b 00000000 0817fbfc 0817fc2c 0x802cf80
0817fc2c 734ebb5e 04230de0 ecec8d35 04264ec0 0x802cf1b
0817fc58 676e62e4 04230de0 f8d55600 676e6290 boost_thread_vc140_mt_1_60!boost::detail::win32::handle_manager::swap+0x7e
0817fc94 76f57c04 04264ec0 76f57be0 e8d96fcc ucrtbase!thread_start<unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void *)>+0x54
0817fca8 776dad2f 04264ec0 e89a080f 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
0817fcf0 776dacfa ffffffff 776c00b0 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0817fd00 00000000 676e6290 04264ec0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  9c5af7c316b52dce74c542a777786aa1292e9273

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+231
72211c25 83a388000000ef  and     dword ptr [ebx+88h],0FFFFFFEFh

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  88a383

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+231

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: clr

IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  59cf5105

STACK_COMMAND:  ~7s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+231

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  cfffffff

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  clr.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  clr

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  clr

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  231

BUCKET_ID_MODPRIVATE: 1

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  59cf5105

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  6e5783

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  4.7.2117.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  APPLICATION_HANG_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BusyHang

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  clr.dll!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_cfffffff_clr.dll!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC

TARGET_TIME:  2018-02-28T03:14:53.000Z

OSBUILD:  9600

OSSERVICEPACK:  17415

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

OSEDITION:  Windows 8.1 Server TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2014-10-29 02:58:22

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  141028-1500

BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_r4

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.3.9600.17415

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  5a7d

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_hang_busyhang_cfffffff_clr.dll!thread::raredisablepreemptivegc

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {6a1ff91c-492b-fc00-85f1-6b17a6a44ff6}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

**Update 2:**
I've noticed, that all threads are start with `ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart` and thread 24 starts with `ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk`. Could this information give an advice how thread 24 was started? What is the difference between these entry points?

Comment: What does `!analyze -v -hang` tell you?

Comment: Thread #24 looks very unhealthy, it is running in DllMain() and acquired the loader lock.  When DllMain() blocks then the show is over.  Which thread actually owns the crt_seh_guarded_call lock is not visible.

Comment: Hans, do you know, could i find out the owner of crt_seh_guarded_call lock?

Comment: Try running sosex:!dlk.

Comment: Searching for `RareDisablePreemtiveGC` might give you some [pointers](https://www.google.be/search?hl=nl&q=Thread%3A%3ARareDisablePreemptiveGC&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:nl-BE:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl) on how to continue. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2007/03/12/net-hang-case-study-the-gc-loader-lock-deadlock-a-story-of-mixed-mode-dlls/) might be worth looking into.

Comment: 1) Threads 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 23 have `RareDisablePreemptiveGC` in theirs callstack. And all these threads are waiting for GC. This is actually the way, i've found out, that this deadlock is caused by GC.
2) my situation is very similar to [Mixed DLL Loading Problem](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290048(vs.71).aspx), the difference is - i have no maxied DLL. There is mixed EXE (which compiles without LNK4210 and LNK4243)